# PHP File Contents as String - Keep Format

Tags: php

I haven't been able to find a solution similar to my problem.

I have a file on a server (UNIX). The file is in a readable format on the server (ie includes spaces, tabs, and newlines as `^M`).

If I `var_dump()` the file it keeps the format but if I `echo` it removes all whitespace and newlines. Is there a way to display this file the same as it would be viewed on the server? below is the way I was attempting to do this:

```
if($login){
    $file = 'ftp://'.$username.':'.$password.'@'.$server.$path;
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    var_dump($contents);//is a string
    $contents = str_replace("^M","<br>",$contents);
    echo $contents;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP isn't removing the spaces, the browser is doing it because you're echoing into an HTML web page. You need to tell the browser not to reformat it.

```
$contents = nl2br($contents);
echo "<pre>$contents</pre>";
```

You should also use the built-in `nl2br()` function to add `<br>` tags, rather than `str_replace()`. Although this isn't really needed inside `<pre>` tags.